# Stuck in the GRUB Terminal After Re-enabling Bitlocker

Tags: command-line, 20.04, grub2

I recently downloaded Ubuntu Studio with the "install alongside Windows" option from the installer. This installer asked me to temporarily disable BitLocker encryption on my Windows 11 OS, so I did that, and everything worked as intended for a day or so.

Then, I tried re-enabling BitLocker encryption on Windows 11. After doing so and booting into GRUB2, I found that it loaded into the "minimal BASH line editing is supported" terminal mode. Disabling BitLocker again produces the same issue.

I can still boot perfectly into Windows 11 by changing my boot manager to "Windows" in my BIOS, but I am completely unable to open Ubuntu from GRUB2 (or anywhere for that matter). I can't uninstall Ubuntu either, the partition deletion method and the os-uninstaller methods both don't work.

Is there a way to either:

1. Uninstall Ubuntu from this state?
2. Get Ubuntu running again?

Thank you!

Comment: Turn off bit locker and what happens?

Comment: When I turn off BitLocker, the problem still remains.